# Issue with selecting an image

Tags: css, sass

Sorry for the simplicity of this question. This doesnt work by any way, I dont know what else to do.

This image shouldnt be selected? I've tried lot of ways to select it but its not being selected.

I may be making a fool mistake.

HTML

```
<div class="social-media__banner">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">
                <img id="icon-test" src="images/github.svg" alt="github">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">

            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">

            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.social-media__banner {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:500px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  ul{

    left: 0rem;
    width: 30px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    li{
      margin: 0 10px;
      list-style: none;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 20px 20px;
      color: white;
      a{
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;



      }
    }
  }  
}

#icon-test{
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 11px;
}
```

*I've checked on the inspector tool and it does not even select.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If not for the cleanliness alone, why nest all of those selectors? Stick with the basics and you won't go wrong. You are saving yourself having to write `.social-media__banner` only a few times in your code.

```css
.social-media__banner {
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top:500px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
 } 
.social-media__banner ul{
    left: 0rem;
    width: 30px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
 }
.social-media__banner li{
      margin: 0 10px;
      list-style: none;
      font-size: 20px;
      padding: 20px 20px;
      color: white;
}
.social-media__banner a{
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: white;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 50%;
        overflow: hidden;
}

#icon-test{
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-media__banner">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="">
                <img id="icon-test" src="https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg" alt="github">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">

            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">

            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Mate, solved the problem, my mistake, SASS was compiled watching for changes on a non existing file, as I moved it into a different folder I the path wasnt right anymore. Anyway thank you and sorry for the fool mistake.